# A tool for sending and receiving plain text via TCP?

Tags: linux, tcp, plaintext, command-line-tool

For debugging purposes, I'm looking for a tool that can do the following:

- Connect to a TCP socket
- send plain text commands
- receive plain text answers

Yes, of course **telnet** can do that. But my problem with the basic telnet clients is that input and output happens in the same window. In case you get many answers from the server (let's say 2 per second), it's not possible to write a longer command because it gets split into multiple pieces.

What I'm looking for is a tool with a separate and isolated command line which isn't influenced by incoming messages.

edit: Linux or Windows.

Comment: What do you want? Basically telnet, but the result from the server is written to a file instead or something?

Comment: Basically telnet, the result should be displayed as always. But imagine you get a new result every 0.5 seconds (periodically, independent of your input) and want to type in a command called "Test-ABC123". You are maybe able to write the first part of the command, let's say "Test-", but in the meanwhile a new result has arrived and "destroys" what you have already written. So my input vanishes before I was able to type in the whole command. I hope it's a bit clearer now, if not then I will post a screenshot of this problem.

Comment: Why not connect to the machine by ssh, and read the debug info from file with tail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux you can do the following in one terminal:

```
telnet superuser.com 80 > ~/output.txt
```

While in another terminal run:

```
tail -f ~/output.txt
```

If you enter `http` commands in the first terminal, you'll see the results on the second.